# How to put each value into array that have been already grouped by a value?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I almost solve this problem but i got stack on how to put a specific value to an array, The idea is to "group by" an array that has the same id and merge all of its value into single property in this case the "character" property, this is already done i have managed to solve it, The problem now is i can't get the value of role property how can i get it? i have tried map but i got an array of role from index 0 to 2. I've also tried _.forEach but the same result im using lodash.

```
var groupArr = [ { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Orc', }, { id: 'David', role: 'hero', character: 'Blade Knight', }, { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Elf', }, { id: 'Steve', role: 'villain', character: 'Undead OverLord', }, { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Wizard', }, ]

var output = _(groupArr).groupBy(a => a.id).map((objs, key) => ({
        'id': key,
        'role': key,
        'character': _.map(objs, 'character')
    }))
    .value();

console.log(output);
```

Comment: While merging, should it replace the value if exists?

Comment: @Jesse - what is the expected result? Can you add an example?

Comment: role should be merchant on array index 0, on array index 1 role should be hero, array index 2 = villain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the role from the 1st item in the group:

```js
var groupArr = [ { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Orc', }, { id: 'David', role: 'hero', character: 'Blade Knight', }, { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Elf', }, { id: 'Steve', role: 'villain', character: 'Undead OverLord', }, { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Wizard', }, ]

var output = _(groupArr)
  .groupBy('id')
  .map((objs, key) => ({
    'id': key,
    'role': _.head(objs).role,
    'character': _.map(objs, 'character')
  }))
  .value();

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: role property should be the role value

Comment: Ok you nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'groupBy' you asked, I let you then make the 'merge'

```
var groupArr = [
    { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Orc', },
    { id: 'David', role: 'hero', character: 'Blade Knight', },
    { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Elf', },
    { id: 'Steve', role: 'villain', character: 'Undead OverLord', },
    { id: 'Jesse', role: 'merchant', character: 'Wizard', }
];


let byId = groupArr.reduce( (acc, i) => {
    acc[i.id] = acc[i.id] || [];
    acc[i.id].push(i);
    return acc;
}, {});


Object.keys(byId).forEach(id => {
   let values = byId[id];
   //Do the merge
});
```

Can also be done like that

```
let merged = [... newSet(groupArr.map(e => e.id))]
.map( id => {
    let values = groupArr.filter( e => e.id === id );
    let merge = {}; //You do
    return merge;
});
```

Comment: This ok but how to do it in lodash?

Comment: It was not clear to me that lodash was mandatory. As I've never used it, I can't tell. Sorry :-/